# Ms Access application be notified on new record in a Sql Server table

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, adodb

Is there a way to be notified when a new entry is entered in a Sql Server table? Using async ADODB maybe? I am using Ms Access. I need a callback in the access application to handle this event.

Comment: You need to send an email on a trigger insert into the table  :  stackoverflow.com/questions/10755469/send-e-mail-from-a-trigger

Comment: Thanks for your response but i need to be notified the ms access application with a callback to handle the event not me.